# MIPS: how to store a string in dynamic memory (heap)

Tags: memory-management, mips

I would like to write a subroutine that takes a string as parameter (from user input) and stores in dynamic memory.

this is what I came up with:

```
    .data
    name: .space 32 # allocates 32 bytes of memory to store a name

    namePrompt: .asciiz "name: "

    .text
    .globl main

main:

    la $a0, namePrompt
    li $v0, 4 # system call to print a string.
    syscall # print namePrompt.

    la $a0, name # adress where to store the input
    li $a1, 32 # max input size in bytes
    li $v0, 8
    syscall

    la $a0, name # name as first parameter of save_string subroutine
    jal save_string



save_string:

    move $s0, $a0 # s0 = name. 

    # allocate 32 bytes in heap memory.
    li $v0, 9 
    li $a0, 32
    syscall

    sw $s0, 0($v0) # store the name in allocated memory

    jr $ra
```

But I have got a feeling this isn't the correct way to do it.

Also how do I free the space afterwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I have got a feeling this isn't the correct way to do it.

No, you're currently just storing the string's address in the heap-allocated memory. If you want to store its contents you need a loop:

```
move $s1,$v0
copy:
  lb $t0,($s0)        # Read one byte from the source address
  sb $t0,($s1)        # Store it at the destination address
  addiu $s0,$s0,1
  addiu $s1,$s1,1
  bne $t0,$zero,copy  # Repeat until the NUL terminator has been copied
```

> Also how do I free the space afterwards?

Assuming that the simulator's `sbrk` calls the host OS's `sbrk` you can pass a negative value to `sbrk` to shrink your program's heap.